# Extrapolating the runtime of mergesort?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

I'm trying to solve the following problem, which asks me to extrapolate the runtime of mergesort to larger inputs. Here's the problem:

> A user runs the code:
>
> ```
> int a=(int*) malloc (N*sizeof(int));
> for (i=0; i<N; i++)
> {
>    a[i] = rand();
> }
> mergesort (a,N);
> ```
>
> This code generates and then orders random numbers for N=10.000.000 and the time it needs is 5.3 sec
>
> Assuming that we have enough memory, which of the following is closest to the runtime for N=1.000.000.000?
>
> 53, 340, 530, 680, 1060, 5300

I thought that as it is a divide and conquer method we have a total of n log n splits, which is 30 for N=1.000.000.000. I know that mergesort's runtime satifies the recurrence T(n) = 2T(n / 2) + n, but, I don't see how to use that to extrapolate the runtime.

How should I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime of mergesort is Θ(n log n). For sufficiently large n (like the numbers you have here), it's not unreasonable to model the runtime as some function of the form cn log n.

One way to approach this problem would be to think about the ratio of the runtime for n = 10<sup>9</sup> to the runtime for n = 10<sup>7</sup>. That gives you

> c 10<sup>9</sup> log 10<sup>9</sup> / c (10<sup>7</sup> log 10<sup>7</sup>)
>
> = 10<sup>2</sup> log 10<sup>9</sup>  / log 10<sup>7</sup>
>
> = 10<sup>2</sup> (9 / 7)
>
> = 128.6

Therefore, you'd expect that the runtime for n = 10<sup>9</sup> to be about 128.6 times the runtime for n = 10<sup>7</sup>. Since the runtime for n = 10<sup>7</sup> is 5.3s, you'd expect the runtime for n = 10<sup>9</sup> to be roughly 681.6s. Therefore, the best answer out of the list would be 680s.

This sort of approach - looking at ratios of runtimes - is a pretty good way to approximate runtimes. We could have also solved this by directly solving for c given that the runtime is of the form cn log n and we know the output for one particular value of n. The reason I chose to use the ratio approach is that it's often helpful for "eyeballing" the runtime. For example, since the runtime is Θ(n log n) and you increased the input size by a factor of 100, it's not unreasonable to guess that the runtime will go up by at least a factor of 100 for the n term, then probably a smaller extra term thrown in on top for the log n term. That alone could lead you to guess that the runtime would be about 680s.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that by using the ratio approach, it doesn't matter what the base of log is. I took the approach calculating c assuming a base of 10 for simplicity and got c=7.57e-8, but ultimately came out with the same 681 value.

Comment: Amazing! I would never choose ratio approach. Thank you both for your immediate reply. templatetypedef than you so much for making that so clear. I really appreciate your time. @Rorrik than you so much for such a useful information!

Comment: @Rorrik Since all logs are multiples of one another (this is one of the fun consequences of the change of base formula) it doesn't matter what base you pick. You just need to pick one and stick with it. :-)